# Printing a page on safari with window.print() doesn't work the second time

Tags: javascript, safari

I am trying to print a page in Safari.

The first time it works fine, but if I click `Cancel` in the print dialog, and then click my print button again, it will just show a blank page on the print preview dialog.

In my case i am trying to print a PDF, so i am creating an invisible iframe and setting the content of it to be a PDF blob. ([based on this library](https://github.com/crabbly/print.js)). But the same thing happens when trying to print the top level window.

Code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-surf-tnuz6?file=/src/index.js